# convolution of two probability density functions

Tags: probability-distributions

Please no one call me dumb - I am not a mathematician and haven't done proper math for the last ten years. But I have a problem at work where I need to perform a convolution of two probability density functions and I have no idea where to start. 
All I know is that the first distribution is:
lognormal

mean = 8

5 percentile = 6

95 percentile = 10.4

Mu - 2.066

Sigma = 0.1665

Second distribution :

lognormal

mean = 4.2

95th = 7.52

Mu = 1.353

Sigma = 0.4044

Can anyone give me a practical way to approach this? Please :)

Comment: By a little Googleing, this seems like a non-trivial problem. I'd probably give some numerical methods a go.